# EKS Service 504 Gateway Timeout - AWS Application Load Balancer Controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

## Context

I have successfully deployed an EKS cluster where I configured and deploy MLflow (v1.27.0) and AWS Application Load Balancer Controller ([chart](https://github.com/aws/eks-charts/tree/master/stable/aws-load-balancer-controller)). Both workloads have been deployed using Terraform and Helm charts.

To validate that the MLflow workload works as intended, I connected to the cluster via kubectl and ran a port-forward command to my local workstation. I am able to successfully access the MLflow dashboard in my browser and everything works as intended. Below is my service definition (generated by the Helm chart installation via Terraform) to highlight the port configuration that I am using for the MLflow service:

**mlflow-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: mlflow
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  creationTimestamp: "2022-08-08T08:08:17Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: mlflow
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mlflow
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.27.0
    helm.sh/chart: mlflow-1.27.0
  name: mlflow
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "2183"
  uid: eb1b2f0f-289b-453a-90b6-c853a60cd9b0
spec:
  clusterIP: 172.20.28.63
  clusterIPs:
  - 172.20.28.63
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: mlflow
    nodePort: 30360
    port: 5252
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5252
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: mlflow
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mlflow
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

In addition to configuring and deploying the AWS Load Balancer Controller chart, I also configured a subdomain in Route53 to point to my load balancer instance via alias routing (this generated an A Record entry), and updated my DNS provider to point to the AWS servers. I validated that everything is configured properly from a DNS perspective. Furthermore, I created a certificate in ACM for SSL encryption and I added the required records to my Route53 configuration. As a confirmation of the validity of the confirmation, my certificate is in the `Issued` state and I can use it as an annotation on my `Ingress` resource definition. Below is my ingress definition and the output of the `kubectl describe ingress my-ingress` command:

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: ACM_CERT_ARN
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: app-lb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: load_balancer_security_group_id
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet_3_id, subnet_4_id
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
  creationTimestamp: "2022-08-08T08:09:11Z"
  finalizers:
  - ingress.k8s.aws/resources
  generation: 1
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "2395"
  uid: 992799bb-3bd5-48fa-9b79-6c9dedab8f6b
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
  - host: public.my_domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: mlflow
            port:
              number: 5252
        path: /mlflow
        pathType: Prefix
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - hostname: app-lb-XXXXXXXXXX.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

**Command Output**

```
> kubectl get ingress my-ingress
NAME          CLASS   HOSTS                    ADDRESS                                                PORTS   AGE
my-ingress    alb     public.my_domain.com     app-lb-XXXXXXXXXX.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com       80      22m

> kubectl describe ingress my-ingress
...
Normal   SuccessfullyReconciled  16s (x2 over 29s)  ingress  Successfully reconciled
```

Another important thing I would like to highlight is that I am not provisioning the AWS Application Load Balancer via Terraform, it is automatically being created through the `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name` annotation on the Ingress resource.

From a networking standpoint, I have provisioned an AWS VPC with 4 subnets:

- subnet_1 (Private Subnet, 10.0.0.0/24 CIDR, AZ eu-central-1a)
- subnet_2 (Private Subnet, 10.0.1.0/24 CIDR, AZ eu-central-1b)
- subnet_3 (Public Subnet, 10.0.2.0/24 CIDR, AZ eu-central-1a)
- subnet_4 (Public Subnet, 10.0.3.0/24 CIDR, AZ eu-central-1b)

The default VPC Security Group is applied to all the subnets in the network. Below the Inbound & Outbound rules:
[image: Inbound Rules for default VPC Security Group]
[image: Outbound Rules for default VPC Security Group]

For the AWS Application Load Balancer (internet-facing) I created a dedicated Security Group with the following rules:
[image: Inbound Rules for AWS Application Load Balancer]
[image: Outbound Rules for AWS Application Load Balancer]

## Issue

Even though I can validate that my MLflow service is running as intended by port-forwarding to my local workstation, if I try to navigate to `public.my_domain.com/mlflow`, I do get automatically redirected to HTTPS, but I end up receiving a `504 Gateway Time-Out` error.

If I simply navigate to `public.my_domain.com` I get back a `404 Reponse` that I can see in the Networking tab of my browser.

I also tried navigating to the AWS Load Balancer URL, but in that case I get a `404 Response` for both `app-lb-XXXXXXXXXX.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com` and `app-lb-XXXXXXXXXX.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com/mlflow`

I would very much appreciate your help on trying to resolve this. My ultimate goal is to be able to access my deployment on `public.my_domain.com/mlflow`.

Am I missing any kind of `alb.*` annotation to be able to successfully expose my service via my custom subdomain or the AWS Load Balancer URL? I'm suspecting that if the issue were related only to my subdomain, I should be able to access the workload on the AWS ALB URL.

Is there any rewrite rule that I should be adding to the annotations? For example, on Google Cloud Platform, I am using NGINX Ingress Controller and I have to add an annotation for this particular case `"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target": "/$2"`

Do I have to update any of my Security Groups to be able to access those resources? My assumption is that if that were the case, I should not even be able to get a `404 Reponse` from the URLs.

Lastly, I am also open to using a different setup (e.g.: AWS Network Load Balancer + NGINX Ingress Controller), but I would very much appreciate a usable reference to any documentation. I initially tried setting up AWS NLB + NGINX Ingress Controller, but could not end up with a satisfactory result.

**EDIT1**

Even though I have not yet been able to find the root cause of this issue, I've taken some additional steps to investigate the issue and made some updates to my configuration:

- To make sure that traffic can flow from the AWS Application Load Balancer to the VPC, I added a new Inbound rule in the VPC Security Group to allow "All Traffic" from the ALB Security Group and a new Outbound rule in the ALB Security Group to allow "All Traffic" to the VPC Security Group
- I noticed that when I define my Ingress resource, it automatically creates a Target Group for the mapped services and that the defined target group is actually unhealthy. This behavior is displayed both with my initial and updated configurations.
  [image: AWS Target Group created by Ingress resource definition is unhealthy]
- I tried configuring my Service resource definition both as `ClusterIP` and `NodePort` and updated the `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type` annotation on the Ingress accordingly
- I added extra annotations to the Service resource definition to specify health check behavior, as I realized MLflow has a dedicated endpoint for this:

  ```
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-path: /health
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-port: "5252"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-protocol: TCP
  ```
- I double checked both the `/` and `/health` endpoints via `curl -I` when port-forwarding the service on my local workstation and both endpoints return a status code of `200`

**EDIT2**
Private subnets have a NAT Gateway configured with the associated route tables defined.

**Private Subnet Route Table**
[image: Private Subnet NAT Gateway Route Table Configuration]

Public subnets have an Internet Gateway configured with the associated route tables defined.

**Public Subnet Route Table**
[image: Private Subnet Internet Gateway Route Table Configuratione]

```
> kubectl describe svc mlflow
Name:                     mlflow
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=mlflow
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=mlflow
                          app.kubernetes.io/version=1.27.0
                          helm.sh/chart=mlflow-1.27.0
Annotations:              meta.helm.sh/release-name: mlflow
                          meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/instance=mlflow,app.kubernetes.io/name=mlflow
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       172.20.206.164
IPs:                      172.20.206.164
Port:                     mlflow  5252/TCP
TargetPort:               5252/TCP
NodePort:                 mlflow  32290/TCP
Endpoints:                10.0.1.11:5252
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

**EDIT3**
I already tried updating the path definition in my Ingress resources with the following entries:

- `/mlflow`
- `/mlflow*`
- `/mlflow/`
- `/mlflow/*`

Regardless of the Ingress path format and type (I tried both `Prefix` and `ImplementationSpecific`), I always keep getting the same error.

Adding below the logs from my AWS Load Balancer Controller and CoreDNS pods.

```
> kubectl logs aws-load-balancer-controller-65768c7bd4-5zh9t -n kube-system  
{"level":"info","ts":1661337648.830114,"logger":"controllers.ingress","msg":"creating loadBalancer","stackID":"default/ingress","resourceID":"LoadBalancer"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337649.143063,"logger":"controllers.ingress","msg":"created loadBalancer","stackID":"default/ingress","resourceID":"LoadBalancer","arn":"arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:832003983940:loadbalancer/app/app-lb/fb8f025c92f17f99"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337649.1980903,"logger":"controllers.ingress","msg":"creating listener","stackID":"default/ingress","resourceID":"80"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337649.262167,"logger":"controllers.ingress","msg":"created listener","stackID":"default/ingress","resourceID":"80","arn":"arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:832003983940:listener/app/app-lb/fb8f025c92f17f99/58d7bed72dc5a575"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337649.2622535,"logger":"controllers.ingress","msg":"creating listener","stackID":"default/ingress","resourceID":"443"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337649.4499094,"logger":"controllers.ingress","msg":"created listener","stackID":"default/ingress","resourceID":"443","arn":"arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:832003983940:listener/app/app-lb/fb8f025c92f17f99/5cb08a47d89149c3"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337649.5827081,"logger":"controllers.ingress","msg":"creating listener rule","stackID":"default/ingress","resourceID":"443:1"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337649.6701205,"logger":"controllers.ingress","msg":"created listener rule","stackID":"default/ingress","resourceID":"443:1","arn":"arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:832003983940:listener-rule/app/app-lb/fb8f025c92f17f99/5cb08a47d89149c3/c246154c528e7f81"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337649.670285,"logger":"controllers.ingress","msg":"creating targetGroupBinding","stackID":"default/ingress","resourceID":"default/ingress-mlflow:5252"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337649.7510114,"logger":"controllers.ingress","msg":"created targetGroupBinding","stackID":"default/ingress","resourceID":"default/ingress-mlflow:5252","targetGroupBinding":{"namespace":"default","name":"k8s-default-mlflo-17cef2d176"}}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337649.8379247,"logger":"controllers.ingress","msg":"successfully deployed model","ingressGroup":"default/ingress"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337649.8394184,"msg":"registering targets","arn":"arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:832003983940:targetgroup/k8s-default-mlflo-17cef2d176/9e67c879c5aee34a","targets":[{"AvailabilityZone":null,"Id":"i-0c7dd86bd788d7173","Port":31564}]}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337649.9140155,"msg":"registered targets","arn":"arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:832003983940:targetgroup/k8s-default-mlflo-17cef2d176/9e67c879c5aee34a"}

> kubectl logs aws-load-balancer-controller-65768c7bd4-lj4bs -n kube-system  
{"level":"info","ts":1661337543.0539248,"msg":"version","GitVersion":"v2.4.2","GitCommit":"77370be7f8e13787a3ec0cfa99de1647010f1055","BuildDate":"2022-05-24T22:33:27+0000"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337543.0877683,"logger":"controller-runtime.metrics","msg":"metrics server is starting to listen","addr":":8080"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337543.0911741,"logger":"setup","msg":"adding health check for controller"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337543.0913644,"logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"registering webhook","path":"/mutate-v1-pod"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337543.0941734,"logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"registering webhook","path":"/mutate-elbv2-k8s-aws-v1beta1-targetgroupbinding"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337543.0943336,"logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"registering webhook","path":"/validate-elbv2-k8s-aws-v1beta1-targetgroupbinding"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337543.0944283,"logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"registering webhook","path":"/validate-networking-v1-ingress"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337543.0944858,"logger":"setup","msg":"starting podInfo repo"}
I0824 10:39:05.094659       1 leaderelection.go:243] attempting to acquire leader lease kube-system/aws-load-balancer-controller-leader...
{"level":"info","ts":1661337545.094871,"logger":"controller-runtime.manager","msg":"starting metrics server","path":"/metrics"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337545.0950024,"logger":"controller-runtime.webhook.webhooks","msg":"starting webhook server"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337545.0952883,"logger":"controller-runtime.certwatcher","msg":"Updated current TLS certificate"}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337545.0953963,"logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"serving webhook server","host":"","port":9443}
{"level":"info","ts":1661337545.0957239,"logger":"controller-runtime.certwatcher","msg":"Starting certificate watcher"}

> kubectl logs coredns-78666889b9-hwpqc -n kube-system  
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 47d57903c0f0ba4ee0626a17181e5d94
CoreDNS-1.8.7
linux/amd64, go1.17.7, a9adfd56
```

Comment: could you share your kubectl get service yaml output ? and kubectl describe service?

and did you configure the NAT Gateway on your private subnets? and configure the Route Table for private subnets through Nat Gateway?

Comment: @gumelaragum the answer is yes to all of your questions. I've now updated my answer to include the route table configuration & associations. I also added the `kubectl describe svc` output. For the service yaml output, it's already part of my question under the `mlflow-service.yaml` section.

Comment: seem the routing is correct, why did you not using route53 alias record to alb seevice? instead using A record to alb IP?

Comment: and whats the log of aws load balancer controller and external-dns?

Comment: ah, and try to use `path: /mlflow*` or `path: /mlflow/*` , with wildcard `*`, iirc this is needed for AWS ALB ingress manifest

Comment: thanks for following up on this - also, when I referred to having an A Record created, Route53 created it when I did the Alias routing because I simply pointed the subdomain to the Alias of the ALB. When it comes to the Ingress resource, I've already tried multiple path formats and types; I've now updated my post to include the additional information you requested

Comment: when not using /mlflow* ? its success? I mean just use /*, if success then seem the app not handled the prefix path / endpoint correctly

Comment: I already tried that both as a `Prefix` and `ImplementationSpecific` rule. Same behavior with `504 Gateway Time-out` error. This happens both for my custom domain URL as well as for the AWS ALB URL.

Comment: how about instance security group? inbound rule or outbound rule? did the outbound rule of the instance security group allow 0.0.0.0? and inbound security group allow from alb?

Comment: yes - on the VPC SG I have an ingress rule to accept all traffic coming from the ALB  Security Group. On the ALB Security Group, I have inbound rules to accept traffic from all sources (internet) and an Egress rule to the VPC SG.

Comment: the instance / ASG need to have outbound rule to 0.0.0.0, not just ALB

Comment: both the VPC SG and the ALB SG have the outbound rule to 0.0.0.0

Comment: the ec2 instance outbound rule?

Comment: that outbound rule was configured properly as well - I think I might have found the issue (related to cluster configuration) - will try to draft an answer

Answer (score 0):

After more than 10 days of investigating this issue, I think I might have found the issue that prevented my services to be accessed via the custom domain URL.

When provisioning my tech stack via Terraform, I am creating two security groups with the following Ingress/Egress rules:

- VPC Security Group

  ```
  ingress {
    description      = "TLS ingress traffic"
    from_port        = 443
    to_port          = 443
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = [aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block]
  }

  ingress {
    description      = "RDS ingress traffic"
    from_port        = 5432
    to_port          = 5432
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = [aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block]
  }

  ingress {
    description      = "ALB ingress traffic"
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    security_groups  = [aws_security_group.alb.id]
  }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }
  ```
- ALB Security Group

  ```
  # HTTPS Ingress
  ingress {
    description      = "TLS ingress traffic"
    from_port        = 443
    to_port          = 443
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

  # HTTP Ingress
  ingress {
    description      = "HTTP ingress traffic"
    from_port        = 80
    to_port          = 80
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = [var.vpc_ipam_pool_cidr_block]
  }
  ```

However, when provisioning my EKS cluster via Terraform, I was only specifying the following parameters in the `vpc_config` block under the assumption that the VPC Security Group gets automatically applied to cluster resources by propagating through the subnets:

```
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids              = var.eks_subnet_ids
    endpoint_public_access  = var.eks_endpoint_public_access
    endpoint_private_access = var.eks_endpoint_private_access
  }
```

Even if I explicitly map the VPC and ALB Security Groups to the EKS cluster when provisioning it, Terraform is always creating a new Security Group for the EKS cluster, which does not have the appropriate Ingress/Egress rules. Thus, I had to update my Terraform configuration with the following entry:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "eks_ingress_from_alb" {
    depends_on = [
      aws_eks_cluster.cluster
    ]

    security_group_id        = aws_eks_cluster.cluster.vpc_config.cluster_security_group_id 
    type                     = "ingress"
    protocol                 = "-1"
    from_port                = 0
    to_port                  = 0
    source_security_group_id = var.alb_security_group_id
}
```

After making this update, the EC2 Target Group became healthy and I was able to access the MLflow service via the custom subdomain. However, I was only able to access it on the `/` path and not on a sub-path such as `/mlflow`.